how to connect DNS on android using java
I want to connect my Android device to a DNS. I tried some libraries and so many ways, but they did not work. How can I do this? Afterward, I wrote a Java code that changes the device settings to alter the DNS settings.
package lib.alor28.net.server;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkCapabilities;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Settings;

public class PrivateDnsManager {

    // Method to enable Private DNS on Android device
    public static void enablePrivateDns(Context context, String hostname) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (connectivityManager != null) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
                    if (capabilities != null && capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                        // For cellular networks in Android 10 and above
                        Settings.Global.putString(context.getContentResolver(), "private_dns_mode", "hostname");
                        Settings.Global.putString(context.getContentResolver(), "private_dns_specifier", hostname);
                    } else {
                        // For Wi-Fi networks in Android 10 and above
                        Settings.Global.putString(context.getContentResolver(), "private_dns_mode", "opportunistic");
                        Settings.Global.putString(context.getContentResolver(), "private_dns_specifier", hostname);
                    }
                } else {
                    // For Android versions before Q
                    Settings.Global.putString(context.getContentResolver(), "private_dns_mode", "hostname");
                    Settings.Global.putString(context.getContentResolver(), "private_dns_specifier", hostname);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Method to disable Private DNS on Android device
    public static void disablePrivateDns(Context context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Settings.Global.putString(context.getContentResolver(), "private_dns_mode", "");
            Settings.Global.putString(context.getContentResolver(), "private_dns_specifier", "");
        }
    }
}


When I attempt to work with this code, I encounter an error message stating, 'Permission denial: writing to settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS.' I've already coded to obtain this permission, yet the error persists even on the 'VIVO Y02' device running Android 12.
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String primaryHost = primaryHostInput.getText().toString().trim();

                // Check if the app has permission to write secure system settings
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
                        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Setting_Activity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS)
                                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // If the app does not have permission, request it
                    final int REQUEST_CODE_WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS = 1001;
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Setting_Activity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS},
                            REQUEST_CODE_WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS); // Add request code here
                } else {
                    // Open network settings to guide users to Private DNS settings
                    // openNetworkSettings();

                    // Enable Private DNS (if the device supports it and the app has necessary permissions)
                    if (isPrivateDnsSupported()) {
                        PrivateDnsManager.enablePrivateDns(Setting_Activity.this, primaryHost);
                    }
                }
            }

**Could someone please help me connect to a DNS? **
